# Why does my script output "module missing" when run?

Tags: python

I downloaded a python project from GitHub and it downloaded an egg file in site-packages file. When I try to run a python file with the imported files it says that one of the modules is not found. I checked the egg file by turning it into `.zip` and I saw the module file there.

How can I solve this problem?

Edit: I got the egg from github "https://github.com/agermanidis/SnapchatBot". I want to make a simple python script so that when someone adds me on snap, it automatically sends it back. The py file for this is already in the examples pre-made by the author, but it outputs this:

```
$ python autowelcomebot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autowelcomebot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from snapchat_bots import SnapchatBot, Snap
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\snapchat_bots-0.1-py3.7.egg\snapchat_bots\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snap'

enter code here
```

Comment: Can you post the egg, the module, any errors, how you're running it, and any other information that can help us debug the issue alongside you?

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

pip install module-name

copy pasting wont work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `pip` to install the required modules; it is the preferred installer program.

Basic usage:

```
python -m pip install SomePackage
```

Comment: The modules are installed  using a setup.py with setuptools and distutils.core. The thing is the files are installed but they are not linked together. The __init__.py imports the modules from the othe python files but it outputs module not found.